# jquery-1.9.1.min.js isn't precompiled while deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I get the error:

`ActionView::Template::Error(jquery-1.9.1.min.js isn't precompiled)` while accessing a page in my application which has the include tag: `<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.9.1.min"%>`

Note that my views are working on all the other pages which incidentally doesn't have the previously mentioned include tag.

I've set my `config/application.rb` to have `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` and I've also done `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` locally. I then pushed to heroku but I'm still seeing the error in the Heroku logs.

Note that `jquery-1.9.1.min.js` was downloaded locally and put it in `vendoer\assets\javascripts` for my app, but I don't think that's the issue because I have other javascripts in that folder which are working on the other pages that are accessible in production.

My application.js has the following:

```
//= require jquery-1.9.1.min
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.numeric
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap
```

which works fine in development. My gemfile has `gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'` if that is relevant.

Finally, in production.rb I tried added `config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery-1.9.1.min.js, highstock.js )` and using `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`.

Due to both `rake assets:precompile` my `public/assets` has an `application.js` which already has the code of the compiled `jquery-1.9.1.min` and it also has a separate file `jquery-1.9.1.min` so it looks like it was compiled twice. I don't think that's the issue though...

I can't figure this out. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried `heroku run rake assets:precompile`

Comment: @abhir yup I did try that. It's okay though my workaround is working. I just let Heroku do the asset precompiling

Comment: cool - keep in mind, the only issue is that if you have a lot of assets, you might slow down load time. good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I figured a work around to this beast. I think the ',' in `config.assets.precompile += %w(...,...)` was affecting the precompile. I took out the ','. I also set `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true` and cancelled any precompiling on my end with `rake assets:clean`

Now heroku does the precompiling and it works.